# Inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{\frac{1}{1+2i\pi f}+\frac{1}{3+2i\pi f}}{\frac{2}{1+2i\pi f}-\frac{2}{4+2i\pi f}}$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I wanted to calculated the inverse fourier transform of the folowing function :
$\frac{\frac{1}{1+2i\pi f}+\frac{1}{3+2i\pi f}}{\frac{2}{1+2i\pi f}-\frac{2}{4+2i\pi f}}$
($f$ is the variable)

I tried the exponential form, Unifying the denominators but in vain, the premitive is still impossible to be found !

can I get some help ?  much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After simplifying, we have $$H(f) =\frac{\frac{1}{1+2i\pi f}+\frac{1}{3+2i\pi f}}{\frac{2}{1+2i\pi f}-\frac{2}{4+2i\pi f}} = 1 + \frac{2 i f \pi}{3} + \frac{i}{-9 i + 6 f π}$$
Now use these facts $$\mathcal{F}\{g'(x)\} = 2\pi i f G(f)$$ $$\mathcal{F}\{e^{-ax}u(x)\} = \frac{1}{a + 2\pi i f}$$ $$\mathcal{F}\{\delta(x)\} = 1$$
You can [check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20fourier%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B2i%5Cpi%20f%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%2B2i%5Cpi%20f%7D%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B1%2B2i%5Cpi%20f%7D-%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B4%2B2i%5Cpi%20f%7D%7D%29) your result(Be careful about the scaling factors which are result of how the Fourier transform is defined).